# Trying to set the focus/hover Foreground color on all buttons in a XAML Win 10 UAP

Tags: xaml, hover, win-universal-app

Been trying to find a way to set a default font color for buttons when the user hovers over them. At moment they all default to black. If I was doing this in HTML/CSS I would use a hover style, but can't seem to figure out how to do the same effect in XAML.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks,
Coop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two avenues here.

You can either override the button's default style (which determines a button's hover color). You can find most XAML controls default styles [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx) or on your computer in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.<WindowsBuildNumber>.0\Generic` by default. The files `generic.xaml` and `themeresources.xaml` have all the default style and theme definitions.

An easy way to generate a copy of an existing control's default style is to open your page (or whatever) up in Blend, right click on an instance of that control, and select "Edit Template" -> "Edit Copy". That'll create a copy of the style for that control. Note that if you use Blend to generate a copy of a Style for you, it'll automatically give it a name. If you want to override the style of EVERY button, you don't your Style to have a name, i.e.:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <!--Your custom style goes here-->
</Style>
```

Then, the part of the style you'd be changing would be this section:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

See the ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrame with a Storyboard.TargetName of ContentPresenter, and a Storyboard.TargetProperty of Foreground? That's the part that changes the button's text color when it gets hovered over. So all you have to do is change its value from {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush} into whatever you want it to be. Note that a Button's Foreground property expects a Brush, but hex color codes will be implicitly converted into a SolidColorBrush, so you can just use, for example, #FFFFFF as your value.

Or, you see how in the default style, the button just uses the value of {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush} to determine the Foreground color? You can actually override that brush. Since it's a ThemeResource, you'd want to override it in a Theme Dictionary. So, in your App.xaml, you'd want to do something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="your light theme color here"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default"> <!--The dark theme is considered "default".-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="your dark theme color here"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!--And for extra bonus points....-->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" Color="your high contrast theme color here"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Be mindful though, that lots of different styles rely on that Brush, so changing it will probably have lots of unintended side effects.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, works perfectly. Found a couple similar 'solutions', but all where missing a bit or based of WPF. Great to have the whole process together and working :)